# ASP.NET publish button

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any button or shortcut that can make publish job instead of clicking to Build->Publish->...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Alt+B+H will bring up the Publish dialog box.

Answer (score 4):

I think only option is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You could add your own shortcut using Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard.

The "Build.PublishSelection" command is the one to look for.

Answer (score 2):

Best way I have found so far in VS2017 is to turn on the toolbar named "Web One Click Publish", then use the "Publish Web" button on the toolbar. I am trying to figure out how to assign a shortcut to this special "Publish Web" button but have not found that yet.